# I want to export a schema using expdp with the following SQL-Statement -> ORA-39001

Tags: database, oracle11g, schema, oracle-sqldeveloper, datapump

I want to export a database Schema with the following SQL-Statement. For the moment I use the SQLDeveloper. In the future I want to use this Statement with Java.

```
DECLARE
  schemaName    VARCHAR2(200) := 'Example';
  dirName       VARCHAR2(200) := '/dir/exampleDir';
  dumpFile      VARCHAR2(200) := 'TestFile.dmp';
  directory     VARCHAR(100)  := 'EXPORT_DIR_' || schemaName;
  handle        NUMBER;
  status        VARCHAR2(20);

BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY ' || directory || ' AS ''' || dirName || '''';

  handle := DBMS_DATAPUMP.OPEN(
    operation => 'EXPORT',
    job_mode  => 'SCHEMA',
    job_name  => 'TEST_EXPORT_' || schemaName);

  DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE(handle, dumpFile, directory);

  DBMS_DATAPUMP.METADATA_FILTER(
    handle => handle,
    name   => 'SCHEMA_EXPR',
    value  => 'IN (' || schemaName || ')');

  DBMS_DATAPUMP.START_JOB(handle);
  DBMS_DATAPUMP.WAIT_FOR_JOB(handle, status);

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP DIRECTORY ' || directory;

END;
```

I get the error massage "ORA-39001"

Can anyone help me please? I dont know, how can I solve this problem. I read any informationen about this error massage. Is the problem the directory or what? I would be very thankful if you can help me. I am sorry about my bad english Knowledge.

Comment: please include the ENTIRE oracle error stack...something like like ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39000: bad dump file specification
ORA-31640: unable to open dump file "E:\dmps\mydmp_01.dmp" for read
ORA-27041: unable to open file
OSD-04002: unable to open file
O/S-Error: (OS 3) The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: also ''/dir/exampleDir' - I don't think that's a valid Oracle DIRECTORY name. An oracle Directory is a db object that references a directory on your file system

Comment: do a select * from dba_diretories, confirm that DIRECTORY_NAME map to what you're supplying to dirName

Comment: Thank you for your help. i do  (select * from all_directories) and I can see the Directory_Name (EXPORT_DIR) and dthe Directory_Path (/temp/dumps). And I can be sure, that the DB Object for the real directory is set. Thanks for that.

But I dont understand, what I have to change in the code?

Would it be too much to ask if you could write me the code. I'm ashamed to ask but I can not find a solution for 2 weeks :((

Comment: Oh, and here is the entire error stack:

ORA-39001: Ungültiger Argumentwert
ORA-06512: in "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", Zeile 79
ORA-06512: in "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", Zeile 3507
ORA-06512: in "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", Zeile 3756
ORA-06512: in Zeile 17
39001. 00000 -  "invalid argument value"
*Cause:    The user specified API parameters were of the wrong type or
           value range.  Subsequent messages supplied by
           DBMS_DATAPUMP.GET_STATUS will further describe the error.
*Action:   Correct the bad argument and retry the API.

Comment: I have a question: Do I need DBA privileges to execute a data pump export?

Comment: you need execute privs on the data pump packages and you need read/write privs on that directory 'grant READ, WRITE on directory "DATA_PUMP_DIR" to <user>';

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do I have execute the grant statement? Because when I execute it, I get the followin error stack:

ORA-01749: Sie können sich selbst keine Berechtigungen erteilen/entziehen
01749. 00000 -  "you may not GRANT/REVOKE privileges to/from yourself"

Comment: you need an admin level account to that, login as SYSTEM or send a request to your DBA

Comment: Thank you. When the DBA give me Data Pump Pack package privileges (DATAPUMP_EXP_FULL_DATABASE and DATAPUMP_IMP_FULL_DATABASE). Then i can execute a Data pump? Is that right?

Answer (score -1):

Tahnk you very much.

> also ''/dir/exampleDir' - I don't think that's a valid Oracle
>   DIRECTORY name. An oracle Directory is a db object that references a
>   directory on your file system

that is only an example. I know that the oracle Directory is a db object that references a directory on the file system. But the directory in my sql statement and the directory on the file system are the same.

Comment: this isn't an answer

Comment: I am sorry about that. I use it the first time. Next time i will do it right

Comment: No worries, not a big deal!